# Container with box-sizing and inside position-fixed bar

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a problem with the box-sizing.
I set it for container `#container`, which gave `padding-right: 222px;`
Inside the container I want to insert bar with `position: fixed` width of 100%.
Fixed but adapts to the screen instead of the container.
Can you help?

Link:
[Demo](http://cdpn.io/byKfA)

Comment: use position: absolute for the one inside

Comment: If you're referring to your `padding-left: 222px` - that won't affect an element that is absolutely positioned - set your inner element to relative in that case.  Sorry I misread the question.

Comment: It's ok. :)
Of course i can set custom with with js but for what?
I really believe than somebody will have better idea. :)

Comment: lol no no im saying there's only one thing you have to change in your entire code - replace what I told you (`position: absolute;`) with `position: relative;` and it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

**Officially:**

```
#container {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
#info_bar {
    position: relative;
}
```

You can still use `top: 0; left: 0;` in the `#info_bar` if you want but I took them out since it was unnecessary.  You can decide if you need it or not.

[image]

### [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gumpe)

Comment: The bar must always adhere to the top, regardless of the amount of content, which is why I used position: fixed.

Comment: Yeah I hit "save" on that answer too soon there was one more thing to change - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gumpe it's fixed there

Comment: Look one more time at what I have above and click the demo link again (the one I put that says "Codepen Demo"

Comment: I tried to use it, but your code caused that the text does not scroll, that nothing has changed.
The website needs to function properly regardless of the amount placed content (scroll up) and the bar has always adhere to the upper edge.